# Why does list.sort return none when you make it a variable?

Tags: python

Hello guys so I am learning a bit of python and currently I am trying to sort lists.

my python code

```
def len_sorting(var1, var2):
    if len(var1) == len(var2):
            return 0
    elif len(var1) > len(var2):
            return 1
    else:
            return -1 

list.sort(cmp=len_sorting)
print list.sort(cmp=len_sorting)
```

This works fine but when I trie to place the list.sort in a variable and print it it returns None

code

```
sorted_list = list.sort(cmp=len_sorting)
print sorted
reverse_sorted = list.sort(cmp=len_sorting, reverse=True)
print reverse_sorted
```

both will return None

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In an unrelated note, you could shorten your function to one line: `return len(var1) - len(var2)`

Comment: `print list.sort(cmp=len_sorting)` "works" (i.e. it prints the sorted list) for you? That shouldn't be the case--it should print `None` (and indeed that's the behavior I see for Python 2.6.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it modifies the `list` **in-place** so it doesn't return anything. In the other hand you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) which will return the modified list.